# Why doesn't Scala IDE recognise my Scala packages?

Tags: eclipse, gatling, scala-ide

I have a project containing our Gatling performance tests. I've imported the Maven project into Scala IDE, and I can see that the project has a Scala nature.

However, when I look at the package tree in the package explorer (it's located in `src/test/scala`), I see the regular folder hierarchy instead of it being flattened by package:

[image: package explorer]

Furthermore, automatic imports, ctrl+click and basically every other IDE feature do not work.

What would I have to configure?

(I'm not that familiar with both Scala and Maven, so I'm not quite sure what other info is relevant here - do enlighten me if I missed anything.)

Comment: Right Click -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder ?

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much - I was hoping it would be such a small thing. If you post it as an answer I can expect it and you can indulge in some sweet, sweet karma :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Right Click` -> `Build Path` -> `Use as Source Folder`.

Any folder can become a source folder by adding it to the Java build path. Build path is basically "stuff" (jars, files and folders) that compiler will consider when compiling your source files.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. To those with my low level of knowledge coming across this question later: I think adding the Scala nature to your project is required as well. `Right Click` the project folder -> `Configure` -> Add Scala Nature` in Eclipse 4.5.1.

Comment: I rarely see someone using Maven with Scala, usually sbt is preferred(or TypeSafe activator, which "contains" sbt). It has [sbteclipse](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) plugin so when you do `sbt eclipse` it generates Eclipse Scala project files for you. I'm not that familiar with Maven, but it seems that there exists a plugin for it also [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html).

Comment: Good addition. I haven't set up this project, but as the rest of the project (i.e. the thing that is being load tested) is in Java, I guess it makes sense for us to use Maven.